# Is it possible to cycle through django model object fields?

Tags: django

I have a user & user_profile model and I've allowed signup with nullable fields so user can fill profile later but I want the app to check if any profile fields are null after every login. Is it possible to cycle through django model object fields?

I tried the below code and got 'uProfile is not iterable'

```
def profile_Populated(usr):
    for x in usr:
       if x == 'null':
            return False
    return True

if profile_Populated(request.user.uProfile) == True:
        pass
    else:
        return redirect("account:profile_edit")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking for `None` values in the record's `__dict__`:

```
record = request.user.profile

has_empty_value = any([v in record.__dict__.values() if v is None])

if has_empty_value:
    return redirect('account:profile_edit')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked, However there's a small syntax issue with your answer. I had to flip the has_empty_value from "any(v in record.__dict__.values() if v is None)" to "any([if v is None v in record.__dict__.values()])"... But thanks anyway. It really helped